# SQL `GROUP BY` and `MAX()`

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

```
Language    Date
----------------------
HTML        2017-03-15
HTML        2017-03-15
HTML        2017-03-19
JavaScript  2017-03-12
JavaScript  2017-03-17
PHP         2017-03-15
PHP         2017-03-17
PHP         2017-03-18
PHP         2017-03-18
```

I need a result grouped by `language` with the second column a `COUNT()` of each language row from the latest date entry. Not all languages have entries on the same dates.

For the table above, results should be:

```
HTML        1
JavaScript  1
PHP         2
```

Comment: I do not get the count part. What you posted 1/1/2 doesn't reflect each language row. Do you mean for specific date? Why is html/js 1 and PHP 2?

Comment: I'm trying to return a count of each language but only the entries from each of of the language's latest entry dates

Comment: Let me see if I understand it correctly: You want the count to reflect the number of UNIQUE dates from the latest date?

Comment: Correct. The latest date of each language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select language, count(*)
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.language = t.language
               )
group by language;
```

This uses a correlated subquery go match the most recent date for each language.  There are other methods, such as using a `join` or:

```
select language, count(*)
from t
where (t.language, t.date) in (select t2.language, max(t2.date)
                               from t t2
                               group by t2.language
                             )
group by language;
```

Comment: Oops, I left out the `group by`.  @AzizSaleh . . . It would have been sufficient to simply say the `group by` is missing.

Comment: I did not notice that, I just ran the query on sql fiddle. My next step was to debug the queries, but you fixed it beforehand. Both are working as expected from the tests I ran. Fiddle link @ http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e823e/12/0

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I had a subquery on a single field, the trick was matching on the second as well.